# Should my question on syntax transformation be split according to source system?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In a comment to my question
[Change syntax from other programs to mathematica syntax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131/change-syntax-from-other-programs-to-mathematica-syntax)

it has been suggested that this question should be split into different questions for sage, maple, latex, etc.

Should I do it?

I also have to note that I did not know at the point of asking this question whether a uniform answer exists.

Answer (score 2):

I think a split would be good, so that each could serve as a definitive reference.